# Header file for cvCalcOpticalFlowLK

Tags: opencv

I am using `cvCalcOpticalFlowLK` function in my code (OpenCV 2.4.1 and Ubuntu 12.04).
I am missing the header file for and getting this error:

```
opticalflowLK.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
opticalflowLK.c:33:67: error: ‘cvCalcOpticalFlowLK’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone please tell me the header file for `cvCalcOpticalFlowLK`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is [deprecated](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/legacy/doc/motion_analysis.html) that's why you can't use it.

- If you code on `c` (not `c++`) you have to call [cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/video_motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk) instead.
- If you code on `c++` than it's better to use new OpenCV interface and call [calcOpticalFlowPyrLK](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#calcopticalflowpyrlk).

Header for them is `opencv2/video/tracking.hpp`.

Comment: Thansk for quick reply.     Will cvCalcOpticalFlowLK work with C++?   Its not working with C++ as well in my case.

Comment: Yes, it will. Any c code work on c++. See update of my answer.